# Are the groups $\mathbb R/ \mathbb Z $ and $ \mathbb R^2 / (\mathbb Z \times \{0\} )$ isomorphic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups, group-isomorphism, infinite-groups

> Is it true that as groups $\mathbb R/ \mathbb Z \cong \mathbb R^2 / (\mathbb Z \times \{0\} )$ ?

I only know that $\mathbb R \cong \mathbb R^2$ (as groups), but I can see no way to decide whether the said quotients are isomorphic or not. Please help. Thanks  in advance.

Comment: There is a group isomorphism from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R^2$ which sends $1$ to $(1,0)$ (why?).

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** If $\phi:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^2$ is a group isomorphism, what is $\phi(\mathbb{Z})$?  In addition, what is the $\mathbb{R}$-dimension of the $\mathbb{R}$-span of $\phi(\mathbb{Z})$?

Comment: I know that $\mathbb R / \mathbb Z \cong \mathbb R^2 / \phi (\mathbb Z)$ , but I can't seem to say anything more about $\phi (\mathbb Z)$ , could you please elaborate ?

Comment: First, you should try to answer the second question ("In addition, [...]").

Comment: : Sorry but I don;t understand that $\mathbb R$-span thing ...

Comment: $\phi(\mathbb{Z})\cong\mathbb{Z}$ is cyclic, whence it is generated by $v:=\phi(1)$.  Hence, the span of $\phi(\mathbb{Z})$ is ...?

Comment: The span is $\mathbb R \phi (1)$ ? but then what ? please help

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they are isomorphic. This follows from the following:

- The groups $(\mathbb{R},+)$ and $(\mathbb{R}^2,+)$ are isomorphic (which you already know);
- For any two nonzero elements $a,b$ of the group $(\mathbb{R},+)$ are "equivalent" in the sense that a group isomorphism of $(\mathbb{R},+)$ sends one to the other. (What's the isomorphism?)

Now $\mathbb{Z}$ in $\mathbb{R}$ is the subgroup generated by $1$, while $\mathbb{Z} \times \{0\}$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is the subgroup generated by $(1,0)$. Can you see where the argument goes from here?

Comment: Umm , I don't see it . How does it follow ?